# Which of these two is the correct term: Named parameters or Named arguments?

Tags: c#

With respect to C# 4.0, which of these two is the correct term: Named parameters or Named arguments? I find many occurences of both terms hence am quite confused how to mention them (say in formal documentation)?

Comment: I prefer "named arguments", because 'parameters' are part of the function/method's signature, and 'arguments' are the values used to satisfy those parameters. Since the naming in question happens at the point of call, "named arguments" makes more sense (e.g. you're naming the *arguments* so the compiler can associate them with the corresponding parameter name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

parameters have *always* been named; in the context of supplying values for a method, they are *arguments* - however, then name that you are specifying is the *parameter* name. So I can see how it would become mixed up ;p But in the context, we are supplying to name for the compiler to use to resolve the *argument*, so "named arguments" ftw.

More specifically:

> ### 7.5.1  Argument lists
>
> An *argument* with an *argument-name* is referred to as a ***named argument***, whereas an *argument* without an *argument-name* is a ***positional argument***. It is an error for a positional argument to appear after a named argument in an *argument-list*.

Comment: (note there is also a confusing usage in 7.5.1.1 - not sure whether that is correct but a different intent, or a typo)

Answer (score 1):

MS itself [refers to them as "named arguments"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).  They made the language; I'd stick with what they use.

(Unless anyone finds stuff on MSDN referring to "named parameters" in the context of C#.

**EDIT:** Someone did.  Use whatever the hell terminology you want. :)

Comment: The third para in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx refers to them as "parameters". That's why I am confused. When MS itself uses them interchangeably, how am I going to understand which one is the right one to use?

Comment: "Someone did" - no, that was a bad reference to something else.

Comment: Mamta: Since they are synonyms, there is arguable no correct term to use.  Just pick one or the other and stick with it.

Comment: @cdhowie - they *aren't* (quite) synonyms. Parameter != argument.

Comment: @Mamta: The usage you mention in the MSDN article looks like an error. This is a very easy error to make.

Comment: But there are many of us who consider the MSDN library like the gospel. So if articles on the MSDN library are erroneous, who are we to trust? Don't they have reviewers who go over each article?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen them used interchangeably, however I like to use parameters in regards the definition, and arguments in regards the values passed. For example, the following class has a "type parameter":

```
class A<T> { }
```

But the following declaration has a "type argument":

```
var a = new A<string>();
```

Quoting from the C# 4 Specification:

> Since a type parameter can be instantiated with many different actual type arguments, type parameters have slightly different operations and restrictions than other types.

Another quote:

> A fixed-parameter with a default-argument is known as an optional parameter, whereas a fixed-parameter without a default-argument is a required parameter.

The only time (AFAIKnew) the C# spec refers to "named arguments" is in regards to `Attributes`. But when to referring to the new feature, they use "named paramters". So, I would follow that pattern.

**Update**

Marc has a good point that parameters have always been named, but that doesn't mean that arguments can be named now too. The name still belongs to the parameter and the argument is supplied to it. With the new "named parameters" feature, there are potentially two parts to supplying arguments: the argument itself, and the *name of the parameter* it is being supplied to.

```
// The part before the : is the named parameter,
// and the part after the : is the argument
SomeMethod(someParam: someArg);
```

I know this is splitting hairs, but I still think it's a valid point. As far as I'm concerned, you will be understood whether you use "named parameter" or "named argument". (Plus, section 7.5.1 is still glaring at me.)

Comment: I don't see why you were downvoted, I totally agree. The naming we're talking about happens to the *arguments* at the point of call; the parameters are already named.

Comment: "The only time..." No: refer to 7.5.1 (I've quoted it into my answer, for convenience). Named parameters is used when referring to *attribute* classes.,

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion I think that 7.5.1 has it backwards, which is also confirmed by 7.5.1.1 which states:

> If no unique parameter list is found, a parameter list with inaccessible names and no optional parameters is constructed, so that invocations cannot use named parameters or omit optional arguments.

In the call you name the parameter that should accept the argument you pass to it.

```
public static void SayHello(string name = "John Doe", int age = 30)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, I see you're {1} years old.", name, age);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  SayHello(age:42);
}
```

Inside Main I haven't passed any argument to the "name" parameter and I don't need to since it has a default value which makes the argument optional (the parameter is not optional since it obviously exist in the SayHello function). I have however specified that the argument 42 should be passed to the "age" parameter (in other words I have named the parameter in the call). If I could name the arguments I should be able to give them arbitrary names:

> SayHello(language:"vFred", version:7);

The only reason I would see for allowing "named arguments" would be if I use an API which doesn't use descriptive names for the parameters of a method. Then at least I could at the caller site name the arguments so it makes sense. But alas C# does not allow you to give your arguments any names, it does however allow you to specify the name of the parameter that should accept the argument.

This reasoning is of course only valid if you don't think that arguments and parameters are interchangeable but rather that parameters are the list on the called site while arguments are on the caller site, which is at least how C++ defines them.